# How to prevent Hibernate Persistence Object from updating If we set any data to that object?

Tags: hibernate

```
WAObservations observation = getHibernateTemplate().get(WAObservations.class,1);
```

setting some data here and updating the status

```
observation.setObservationStatus(Constants.observation_completed);
```

New records will be generated in the following two dependency tables once the status is updated

```
WAMicroObservations aMicroObservations = new WAMicroObservations();
aMicroObservations.setWaObservationId(observation);
```

Setting some more values related to Micro observations.If any exception occurs here,These two dependency tables are not updated.Its fine.But above WAObservations Table got updated automatically.

```
WAChemObservations aChemObservations = new WAChemObservations();
aChemObservations.setWaObservationId(observation);


getHibernateTemplate().save(aMicroObservations);
getHibernateTemplate().save(aChemObservations);
```

How to prevent the WAObservations Table from updating If any exception raised while executing the code?

Any help,would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess without having a look at your real business code, but I assume you just have to define your transaction boundaries properly. If you want to go the 'all or nothing' approach, define one common transaction for all your operations. Only if all your code completes without any exception, the modification statements will be commited. Otherwise if an exception occurs, a rollback will happen.

Maybe take a look at [declarative transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

At least use `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` instead of the [deprecated HibernateTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its getting updated automatically in spite of using Transaction. Because Here I am setting data to Object retrieved from DB.Hope you understand my issue

Comment: Maybe you can add the real business related to this transaction.

Comment: transactionTemplate.execute(

                new TransactionCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus ts) {

                        try {

                              status.append(Constants.SUCCESS_STATUS);

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            ts.setRollbackOnly();

                            status.append(Constants.FAILURE_STATUS);

                        }

                    }

                });

Comment: I am using the above one for Transaction.Its not getting rolled back Though I mentioned roll back in Transaction.Please help me out in fixing this issue.

Comment: How is this related to the code of your question? Maybe better update your question with the entire business flow (the transaction which wraps all of your code) and please format it in a readable way.